# Raycast LayerMask Ignore

Tags: unity3d, mask, raytracing

Проблема века.. Делаю игру для телефона. Нужно чтобы мобы видели друг сквозь друга. Думаю: "надо поставить layerMask и все будет хорошо". Поставил. мобы не реагируют (указал именно ту маску, которая принадлежит им. Ну а как иначе). Потыкался, потыкался. Ничего. Потом подумал, что может быть из-за того что я layer Collision Matrix поставил. Убрал. Хоть что то бы поменялось (кроме коллизии). Пытался указать номер маски (1 << 11). Тоже никаких реаций замечено не было. В итоге так ничего и не добился. 
Код, который я использовал: 
`RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Start.transform.position, (Player.transform.position - Start.transform.position), lmask);` 
В lmask указал маску моба. Пробовал и без нее, ничего не меняется.
единственная реакция на маску, это если поставить nothing или поставить player. Тогда будет null reference выдавать. [image: Изображение] На изображении восклицательный - значит видит. Вопросительный - не видит. 
C такой проблемой сталкиваюсь впервые. 
Unity 2019.3.0f6

Comment: А нужен ли тут рейкаст? Почему просто не проверить на близость по х?

Comment: @Yaroslav, Нужен. По логике он должен Именно увидеть плеера (спереди), А если не видит,  то реагировать не должен. А реакция, если не видит, по звуку идет. (определенная система шума плеера)